# Check if a field is empty and get value from another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with this structure

table_translations

| name | cat | text_en | text_es | text_pt | text_fr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 01 | one | uno | un | un |
| item1 | 02 | one_B | uno_b |  | un_b |
| item2 | 01 | two | dos | dois | deux |
| item3 | 01 | one | uno |  |  |
| item4 | 01 | four |  |  | quatre |

table1_items

| name | cat | column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 01 | c-1 | c-2 | c-3 |
| item3 | 01 | c-1 | c-2 | c-3 |

table2_items

| name | cat | column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 01 | c-1 | c-2 | c-3 |
| item2 | 01 | c-1 | c-2 | c-3 |

With this query I get the translations for each table_items (there are several table_items):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table1_items, table_translations 
WHERE table_translations.name =  table1_items.name
  AND table_translations.cat = table1_items.cat;
```

| name | cat | column1 | column2 | column3 | text_en | text_es | text_pt | text_fr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 01 | c-1 | c-2 | c-3 | one | uno | un | un |
| item3 | 01 | c-1 | c-2 | c-3 | one | uno |  |  |

However, I would like check if the translation_"language" is empty, then select the value from translation_en. Is that possible?

| name | cat | column1 | column2 | column3 | text_en | text_es | text_pt | text_fr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 01 | c-1 | c-2 | c-3 | one | uno | un | un |
| item3 | 01 | c-1 | c-2 | c-3 | one | uno | one | one |

Comment: [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) to kick

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Probably you need `COALESCE(text_es, text_en), COALESCE(text_pt, text_en), COALESCE(text_fr,text_en)`

Comment: "empty" in the sense of `NULL` or empty string? If it's the first [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) is your friend. But that would require you explicitly name the columns you want to return.  Ie instead of `select *` use `select ..., coalesce(text_es, text_en)...`

Comment: @derpirscher, I mean empty String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional `IF` to check for empty stings

```
SELECT ti.*,
       tt.text_en,
       IF(tt.text_es =  '', tt.text_en,tt.text_es) as text_es,
       IF(tt.text_pt = '', tt.text_en,tt.text_pt) as text_pt,
       IF(tt.text_fr = '', tt.text_en,tt.text_fr) as text_fr
FROM table1_items ti JOIN
     table_translations tt
     ON tt.name =  ti.name AND tt.cat = ti.cat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . you can use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT i.*,
       t.text_en,
       coalesce(t.text_es, t.text_en) as text_es,
       coalesce(t.text_pt, t.text_en) as text_pt,
       coalesce(t.text_fr, t.text_en) as text_fr
FROM table1_items i JOIN
     table_translations t
     ON t.name =  i.name AND t.cat = i.cat;
```

If `NULL` can mean the empty string, then you can use `NULLIF()`:

```
SELECT i.*,
       t.text_en,
       coalesce(nullif(t.text_es, ''), t.text_en) as text_es,
       coalesce(nullif(t.text_pt, ''), t.text_en) as text_pt,
       coalesce(nullif(t.text_fr, ''), t.text_en) as text_fr
```

Comment: Thanks, It works but as I comment before, if the string is empty it doesn't. I had to set to null all the empty fields before.